# can you use c code to read a .txt file size?

Tags: c, file, return, size

this is all very new to me and i'm trying to see if i can return the size of a text file included in a c program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "Test1.txt"

int main()
{

}
```

I'm reading a lot about an fseek function but not sure how to implement it

Comment: Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions here. Please be aware that we do not provide _from-scratch_ coding service here. Please show us what you've tried already, how it failed and we might be able to help.:-)

Comment: You shouldn't #include the text file. Open it using `fopen`, `fseek` to the end, and then, use `ftell`

Answer (score 3):

You're not making sense, I'm afraid.

It doesn't make sense to "include a text file in a C program" like you did. A text file does not contain C code (typically), so it can't be included in C source code. The compiler doesn't know how to deal with that.

The way to *check* the size of a text file, any text file and *not* one "included" in the program, is to use a combination of I/O functions. You need to

1. Open the file with `fopen()`
2. Go to the end of the file with `fseek()`
3. Check the position that you're at with `ftell()`; this will be the size of the file since you know you're at the end
4. Close the file with `fclose()`

The file name can be hardcoded to e.g. `"Test1.txt"` if you want your program to always check the size of the same file, or it can be handled as a command-line argument using `argc` and `argv` (which you've omitted from your `main()`).

Comment: in this task we've been given a .txt file.

is there anyway to read the information from it? or do i need to change it to a .c file ?

Comment: @terribleprogramming Please post a new question, since that it something completely different. Also look for duplicates before posting, I have a hunch that people have asked about how to read stuff from files before, here.